# How to join two 3D numpy arrays so that np.arr(1,m,n) + np.arr(1,m,n) = np.arr(2,m,n)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have several 3-dimensional numpy arrays that I want to join together to feed them as a training set for my LSTM neural network. They are mostly of shape (1,m,n)

I want to join them so that, for e.g. np.arr(1,50,20) + np.arr(1,50,20) = np.arr(2,50,20) and np.arr(1,50,20) + np.arr(3,50,20) = np.arr(4,50,20)

Which of the stack functions of numpy would suit my problem? Or is there another way to solve it more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy `concatenate` with the first axis.

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = rng.integers(0, 10, (1, 3, 20))
b = rng.integers(-10, -1, (2, 3, 20))

c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)

print(c.shape)

(3, 3, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **np.vstack**

```
    x = np.array([[[2,3,5],[4,5,1]]])
    y = np.array([[[1,5,8],[8,0,9]]])
    x.shape
    (1,2,3)    
    np.vstack((x,y)).shape
    (2,2,3)
```